# PHP AJAX Chat how to eat less resources

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

Hi I've been searching through the web different ways to create a live chat with php, I've read about long polling, ajax push (Comet) or what I think would be the best way to go using node.js.
The thing is I'm working on a 1 on 1 facebook style chat which I want to integrate in a script that I want to sell in a marketplace, so it is not for my own use, the problem here is that using node.js would make it more difficult for the customers to install the script so I am trying to find a different way to go that can give some good results without eating to many resources.

I've been thinking a lot about it and came up with an idea (that may get criticised but I need to share it to then see different opinions and decide wether it may be a good way to go or not).
The idea is the next: 
I would have all the chat messages saved in a mysql database, when a user opens a chat conversation he generates a json file that stores the last id of the last message posted, so then instead of checking in database for new messages you would be checking with ajax that json file to see if the id changed, if it changes you would then load the new messages from database.
To make this work each time you post a message into that chat (1 on 1 conversation) you are inserting it to database and also editing the json file with the new id. 
I was also thinking about incrementing the time you check into the json file so that if for example a minute has passed and there hasn't been new messages instead of checking into that file every 3 secc the time would increment to 6 for example, and so on.

It may be a bad idea, I'm just sharing because I am really worried about making this chat work with the best possible performance and I don't really know which way to go, so I want to know if this is a good, bad or terrible idea, also if not good would appreciate any comment on which way to go.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use websockets with php, too, e.g. with ratchet: http://socketo.me/ and I would not store converstions in databases, this will lead to a database size explosion, if your chat system hits off

Comment: Where should I store them then? I mean its a 1 on 1 chat and all conversations should be private... maybe, saving messages till 1 month maximum would fix the size explosion thing?

Comment: Why not just store them in a file for each converation?

Comment: BTW thank you for the socketo link, just checking on it and looks interesting

Comment: but, if I store them in a file, for example in json, they could be accesed by other people then they would not be private conversations

Comment: How can they be accessed by other people?

Comment: If I create a json file and save it onto my ftp this file will be accesible through a browser, at least thats what I understand.

Comment: If you save them in the public folder on your server then of course, everyone can just access them, but usually besides the www folder you can create other folders

Comment: I've heard about that but have never tried it, so would I bee able to access those files through php or jquery?

Comment: Yes, you can store the files outside your webroot, and access them through PHP using their absolute path. (you can't access them directly through jQuery)

Comment: Ok I'll check on that, anyway I don't know why I  thould it was better to store the info in a db but I will check on it ty for the info

Comment: @Ananth it should even be possible accessing them with a relative path by moving up to the folder containing the new folder